# URL Params with Special Characters in Jquery laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

As of now I can access my url params using this code

`acl` params contains `special character` like `+` where the value of this param is

`Very High 15% +`

where In my browser looks like this

link

```
http://localhost/whitelabs/yeast-bank?categoryID=3&searchType=YEAST&keyword=a&acl=Very%20High%2015%%20+
```

JS

```
 $( "#btnSearchYeast" ).click(function() {
        var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
        var categoryID = $( "#selectType2" ).val();
        var acl = $( "#selectType3" ).val();
        location.href="{{ url('yeast-bank') }}"+"?categoryID="+categoryID+"&searchType=YEAST&keyword="+keyword+"&acl="+acl;
        $( "#compareDiv" ).hide();
    });
```

But when I tried to `dd($acl);` on my controller.

It returns something like this

[image]

Where `+` sign is missing now in my controller. How can I get the value of `acl` param as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode your string, as well as [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) on the other end:

```js
const myString = "here + is a % dangerous & string"
const encodedString = encodeURIComponent(myString)
console.log(encodedString);
const decodedString = decodeURIComponent(encodedString)
console.log(decodedString)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to encode this to URI-Format

the correct coded Version is

```
encodeURIComponent( "Very High 15% +")

== 

"Very%20High%2015%25%20%2B"
```